# Android Studio: errors while running my program

Tags: java, android, xml, gradle

I have an issue with my project. After I uploaded it on GitHub, I got the following errors: "Error running 'MainActivity': The activity 'MainActivity' is not declared in AndroidManifest.xml"; -> I fixed it: File - Sync project with Gradle files. After I did that, I got this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnjUF.png. Do you have any idea how to fix it? Thanks guys!

Comment: Hi Samoila, Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be easier if you could post your full Manifest file. May it's some syntax error.

Comment: Go to your Manifest and click on [Merged Manifest](https://i.imgur.com/Vs1fzxI.jpg)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/K9JjndAV

Comment: i figured it out, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Open the manifest file(AndroidManifest.xml) and click on **Merged Manifest**. You can refer the image below:
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgyzj.png)

You can read more about it at the developers documentation of android [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#inspect_the_merged_manifest_and_find_conflicts).